# 2560 x 1440 resolution / dpi problem in Chrome

Tags: display-resolution, intel

I'm having some issues with a 32" 2560 x 1440 monitor. Intel i5 with HD 5500 video chip.
Edit: Fuzzy images. text not sharp.
My monitor shows 2k in System Settings/Display, but when I go to https://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/ it shows 1969 x 1107 instead.

```
$ xrandr
HDMI1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 725mm x 428mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+  74.97  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1440     59.91  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Well then don't visit this website if it shows you incorrect information. From `xrandr`'s output I'd say everything works just fine. Do you encounter any problems? What's your actual question here?

Comment: Let me check: you are using a *web site* to determine your screen resolution? Isn't this both utterly overcomplicated and utterly unreliable? (For me it says 1920 x 1104; I can sort of understand what that number represents, but it is neither the resolution of my monitor, nor the available number of pixels in the client area of the browser; it's just a meaningless number.)

Comment: @ alexp - Javascript can detect screen resolutions. All websites detect resolutions of their visitors (See awstats or google analytics). Thats why I  referenced the site. I was wondering why it differs.  For example http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/display_settings.php . Lagom is a crazy popular site for calibrating monitors. Obviously scaling will mess with it. But at normal scale it should show the correct resolution.

Comment: P.S. Do you have some sort of scaling applied to your desktop? 130% perhaps?

Comment: @dessert Sharpness is not really there. Like the ad on this page looks blurry. Played with monitor settings of course. image setup greyed out where sharpness is. I read that it could be only for vga output?

Comment: @surfos: Javascript can only repeat what the browser tells it; it has no interface to the hardware. All operating systems that I know of which support graphics have one or more native utilities to report the video mode; and, actually, *all monitors can do that too using the OSD*. So, what do your operating system, and, crucially, *your monitor* have to say?

Comment: Nope no scaling. set at 1

Comment: @AlexP So is the real question then: why is my system telling the website that it is running 1969 x 1107? My laptop is only a year old so why would images look fuzzy?

Comment: Maybe you have some sort of scaling *in the browser*? Try playing with the *in-browser* scaling. The web site quoted in the question is sensitive to the in-browser scaling, I checked; the reported values are consistent with 130% scaling in the browser, or with setting pixel density to 125 dpi. For example, in Firefox check (`about:config`) `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` (positive numbers represent scale factors; -1.0 means use operating system's pixel density value).

Comment: Please *always* add additional information directly to your question ([edit]) rather than in comments.

Comment: @AlexP You have an amazing brain. I didn't even think about browser level dpi. (I swear I learn something new everyday)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @AlexP for the direction. And [this site](http://kernpanik.com/geekstuff/2015/05/20/chrome-change-default-hidpi-setting.html) for the answer.

The problem turns out to be Chrome's scaling.

To permanently get back to the nice, calming original scaling factor (=1), you need to edit Chrome's desktop file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

Find the line which contains the path to the binary and change it from

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
```

to

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --force-device-scale-factor=1 %U
```

Save the file (in nano: type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and confirm with <kbd>Y</kbd>) then restart Chrome.

No more eyes bleeding. :)